# Program Help - Solving for e(n)

Tags: c++, algorithm

I've been wrestling with this issue for a week and I just need some guidance on the math part of it.  If I could just understand the math behind it I could piece together the functions to make it work.  The assignment is;

---

**Design and develop a C++ program for Calculating e(n) when delta <= 0.000001**

- e(n-1) = 1 + 1/1! + 1/2! + 1/3! + 1/4! + … + 1/(n-1)!
- e(n) = 1 + 1/1! + 1/2! + 1/3! + 1/4! + … + 1/(n)!

delta = e(n) – e(n-1)

You do not have any input to the program. Your output should be something like this:

- N = 2   e(1) = 2     e(2) = 2.5     delta = 0.5
- N = 3   e(2) = 2.5   e(3) = 2.565   delta = 0.065 
  ...

You must use recursive function calls.

---

My first issue is the math and the variables that would contain them.

- the delta, e(n), and e(n-1) variable must doubles
- if e(n) = 1 + 1 / 1! = 2 then e(n-1) must equal 1, which means delta = 1 (that's my thinking anyway) I'm just not sure of the math behind the .5 delta the first time and the 0.065 in the second iteration.

Can someone point me in the right direction on this problem?

Thank you,

T

Comment: Please post this to  http://math.stackexchange.com/  You will get better results.

Answer (score 1):

From the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29) link, you can see that

[image]

I will not explain the notion of limits here, but what this basically means is that, if we define a function **e** where `e(n) = 1 + 1/1! + 1/2! + 1/3! + 1/4! + … + 1/(n)!` (which is the function given in your problem), we are able to approximate the real value of the constant **e**.
The higher **n** is, the closer we get from **e**.

If you look closely at the function, you can see that each time, we add a term which is smaller than the previous one: `1 >= 1/1! >= 1/2! >= .... >= 1/(n)!`

That basically means that, every time we increase **n** we are getting closer to **e** but we are slowing down in the way.

The real value of **e** is 2.71828...

- In our first step e(1) = 1, we are 1.71828... too far from the real value
- In the second step e(2) = 2, we are at 0.71828..., 1 distance closer
- In the third step e(3) = 2.5, we are now at 0.21828..., 0.5 distance closer

As you can see, we are getting there, but the closer we get, the slower we move. Now let's say that at each step, we want to know how close we have moved compared to the previous value.
We then do simply `e(n) - e(n-1)`. This is basically what the **delta** means.

At some point, we are moving so slow that it does no longer make any sense to keep going. We are almost staying put. At this point, we decide that our approximation is close enough from **e**.

In your case, the problem defines the minimum progression speed to 0.000001

Comment: Thank you.  Does that mean that I could write a recursive function for e(n) like this; 'return n + n / factorial(n)'?

Comment: if you mean `return e(n-1) + 1/fact(n)` then the answer is yes. but you need to put a stop condition, otherwise, your function will run forever. hint: delta = 1/fact(n)

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution :-

```
delta = e(n) - e(n-1)
delta = 1/n!
delta < 0.000001
n! > 1000000
n >= 10  as 10! = 3628800
```